# Custom css for paging in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter, pagination

I need a little help here,

I want using paging CodeIgniter.

Here my piece code for showing the paging.

```
    $this->load->library("pagination");
    $config = array();
    $key = $this->input->get_post('qfront');
    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "source/";
    $config["total_rows"] = $this->fetch_count($key)->count;
    $config["per_page"] = 10;
    $choice = $config["total_rows"] / $config["per_page"];
    $config["uri_segment"] = 2;
    $config["num_links"] = round($choice);
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination"><ul>';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul></div><!--pagination-->';

    $config['first_link'] = '&laquo; First';
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev page">';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['last_link'] = 'Last &raquo;';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li class="next page">';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['next_link'] = 'Next &rarr;';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="next page">';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['prev_link'] = '&larr; Previous';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev page">';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';

    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="page">';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(2)) ? $this->uri->segment(2) : 0;
    $data["results"] = $this->fetch_result($config["per_page"], $page, $key);
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $data["key"] = $key;
    $this->load->view("page", $data);
```

in my view :

```
<?php echo $links; ?>
```

And what I got is
[image]

How can I make like <-prev 1 2 3 4 5 . . . 200 next->

Is it possible? Or maybe a little nice css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `$config` array passed into the pagination `initialize()` method, you can set the number of links to display on either side of the current page with `num_links`:

```
$config['num_links'] = 2;
```

From the [CI user guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html):

> The number of "digit" links you would like before and after the selected page number. For example, the number 2 will place two digits on either side, as in the example links at the very top of this page.

That should get you closer to exactly what you want. I don't know the exact HTML generated by this library, so if you post it maybe someone can give you a CSS solution. You could also look into [extending the CI pagination library](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html) to suit you needs (check out "Extending Native Libraries").

Comment: thx for your comment @matthew, i set to 9, and got look like [imgur](http://imgur.com/IPk3UsF), and when i click page 10, it show [imgur](http://imgur.com/e3HAHlL), why show like that? not show like <prev 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 next> T_T help pls

Comment: @Benikurniawan setting it at 9 will show 9 _per side_, not 9 altogether. When you'e on the first page, it can't show 9 to the left, so it only does on the right. It's a bit weird, I agree.

Comment: @mattew hmm, ok ok, i guess that's the default by pagination library btw thx for answering my question mattew :)