# CodeIgniter pagination customization

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I need to customize codeigniter pagination. Currently pagination on my site is working like this. (I am using CI pagination library)

[image: Current Pagination]

I want my pagination to look and work like this

[image: Required Pagination]

What can I do with codeigniter's pagination library for this?
Is there already any customized library on internet? Or I have to create my own?

My $config array is

```
    $config['first_link'] = false; 
    $config['last_link']  = false;
    $config ['prev_link'] = '<i class="fa fa-caret-left"></i>';
    $config ['next_link'] = '<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>';
    $config ['num_links'] = 2;
    $config ['base_url'] = 'My base url';
    $config ['total_rows'] = 50; 
    $config ["per_page"] = 10;
    $config ["uri_segment"] = 4;
    $config ['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: simply you have to apply css on current pagination and make it like required. Visit this link [how-to-apply-css-styles-to-pagination-in-codeigniter](http://www.iprogrammerindia.in/how-to-apply-css-styles-to-pagination-in-codeigniter/)

Comment: But how can I add " . . . " between the page numbers? like in " < 1 ... 4 5 6 .. 17 > "

Comment: edit your question with $config array's coding you have tried so far. then i can try something. and this answer is may be  useful for you (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20573882/custom-css-for-paging-in-codeigniter)[custom-css-for-paging-in-codeigniter]

Comment: thanks for your help but your referred question wasn't helpful. There was't any solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I came up with the solution by extending CI pagination library.
Created new class Mypagination and overrided the default create_links() method.

Here is the code

```
class Mypagination extends CI_Pagination {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function create_links()
{
    // If our item count or per-page total is zero there is no need to continue.
    // Note: DO NOT change the operator to === here!
    if ($this->total_rows == 0 OR $this->per_page == 0)
    {
        return '';
    }

    // Calculate the total number of pages
    $num_pages = (int) ceil($this->total_rows / $this->per_page);

    // Is there only one page? Hm... nothing more to do here then.
    if ($num_pages === 1)
    {
        return '';
    }

    // Check the user defined number of links.
    $this->num_links = (int) $this->num_links;

    if ($this->num_links < 0)
    {
        show_error('Your number of links must be a non-negative number.');
    }

    // Keep any existing query string items.
    // Note: Has nothing to do with any other query string option.
    if ($this->reuse_query_string === TRUE)
    {
        $get = $this->CI->input->get();

        // Unset the controll, method, old-school routing options
        unset($get['c'], $get['m'], $get[$this->query_string_segment]);
    }
    else
    {
        $get = array();
    }

    // Put together our base and first URLs.
    // Note: DO NOT append to the properties as that would break successive calls
    $base_url = trim($this->base_url);
    $first_url = $this->first_url;

    $query_string = '';
    $query_string_sep = (strpos($base_url, '?') === FALSE) ? '?' : '&amp;';

    // Are we using query strings?
    if ($this->page_query_string === TRUE)
    {
        // If a custom first_url hasn't been specified, we'll create one from
        // the base_url, but without the page item.
        if ($first_url === '')
        {
            $first_url = $base_url;

            // If we saved any GET items earlier, make sure they're appended.
            if ( ! empty($get))
            {
                $first_url .= $query_string_sep.http_build_query($get);
            }
        }

        // Add the page segment to the end of the query string, where the
        // page number will be appended.
        $base_url .= $query_string_sep.http_build_query(array_merge($get, array($this->query_string_segment => '')));
    }
    else
    {
        // Standard segment mode.
        // Generate our saved query string to append later after the page number.
        if ( ! empty($get))
        {
            $query_string = $query_string_sep.http_build_query($get);
            $this->suffix .= $query_string;
        }

        // Does the base_url have the query string in it?
        // If we're supposed to save it, remove it so we can append it later.
        if ($this->reuse_query_string === TRUE && ($base_query_pos = strpos($base_url, '?')) !== FALSE)
        {
            $base_url = substr($base_url, 0, $base_query_pos);
        }

        if ($first_url === '')
        {
            $first_url = $base_url.$query_string;
        }

        $base_url = rtrim($base_url, '/').'/';
    }

    // Determine the current page number.
    $base_page = ($this->use_page_numbers) ? 1 : 0;

    // Are we using query strings?
    if ($this->page_query_string === TRUE)
    {
        $this->cur_page = $this->CI->input->get($this->query_string_segment);
    }
    else
    {
        // Default to the last segment number if one hasn't been defined.
        if ($this->uri_segment === 0)
        {
            $this->uri_segment = count($this->CI->uri->segment_array());
        }

        $this->cur_page = $this->CI->uri->segment($this->uri_segment);

        // Remove any specified prefix/suffix from the segment.
        if ($this->prefix !== '' OR $this->suffix !== '')
        {
            $this->cur_page = str_replace(array($this->prefix, $this->suffix), '', $this->cur_page);
        }
    }

    // If something isn't quite right, back to the default base page.
    if ( ! ctype_digit($this->cur_page) OR ($this->use_page_numbers && (int) $this->cur_page === 0))
    {
        $this->cur_page = $base_page;
    }
    else
    {
        // Make sure we're using integers for comparisons later.
        $this->cur_page = (int) $this->cur_page;
    }

    // Is the page number beyond the result range?
    // If so, we show the last page.
    if ($this->use_page_numbers)
    {
        if ($this->cur_page > $num_pages)
        {
            $this->cur_page = $num_pages;
        }
    }
    elseif ($this->cur_page > $this->total_rows)
    {
        $this->cur_page = ($num_pages - 1) * $this->per_page;
    }

    $uri_page_number = $this->cur_page;

    // If we're using offset instead of page numbers, convert it
    // to a page number, so we can generate the surrounding number links.
    if ( ! $this->use_page_numbers)
    {
        $this->cur_page = (int) floor(($this->cur_page/$this->per_page) + 1);
    }

    // Calculate the start and end numbers. These determine
    // which number to start and end the digit links with.
    $start  = (($this->cur_page - $this->num_links) > 0) ? $this->cur_page - ($this->num_links - 1) : 1;
    $end    = (($this->cur_page + $this->num_links) < $num_pages) ? $this->cur_page + $this->num_links : $num_pages;

    // And here we go...
    $output = '';



    // Render the "Previous" link.
    if ($this->prev_link !== FALSE && $this->cur_page !== 1)
    {
        $i = ($this->use_page_numbers) ? $uri_page_number - 1 : $uri_page_number - $this->per_page;

        $attributes = sprintf('%s %s="%d"', $this->_attributes, $this->data_page_attr, (int) $i);

        if ($i === $base_page)
        {
            // First page
            $output .= $this->prev_tag_open.'<a href="'.$first_url.'"'.$attributes.$this->_attr_rel('prev').'>'
                .$this->prev_link.'</a>'.$this->prev_tag_close;
        }
        else
        {
            $append = $this->prefix.$i.$this->suffix;
            $output .= $this->prev_tag_open.'<a href="'.$base_url.$append.'"'.$attributes.$this->_attr_rel('prev').'>'
                .$this->prev_link.'</a>'.$this->prev_tag_close;
        }

    }

    // Render the "First" link.
    if ($this->first_link !== FALSE && $this->cur_page > ($this->num_links + 1 + ! $this->num_links))
    {
        // Take the general parameters, and squeeze this pagination-page attr in for JS frameworks.
        $attributes = sprintf('%s %s="%d"', $this->_attributes, $this->data_page_attr, 1);

        $output .= $this->first_tag_open.'<a href="'.$first_url.'"'.$attributes.$this->_attr_rel('start').'>'
            .$this->first_link.'</a>'.$this->first_tag_close;
    }


    // Render the pages
    if ($this->display_pages !== FALSE)
    {
        /*
         * On page 4, show hidden page 2
         */ 
        if($start == 4){
            $start--;
        }

        /*
         * On pages after 4, show dots before pages
         */ 
        if(($start)>4){
            $output .= '<div class="continues">. . .</div>';
        }

        /*
         * On page 4th last, show hidden page 2nd last
         */ 
        if($start == ($num_pages-3) && $start > 4){
            $end++;
        }

        /*
         * On last page, show hidden page 3rd last
         */ 
        if($start == $num_pages && $start>3){
            $start--;
        }

        /*
         * On page 1, show hidden page 3
         */ 
        if($start == 1 && $end < $num_pages-1){
            $end++;
        }

        // Write the digit links
        for ($loop = $start -1; $loop <= $end; $loop++)
        {
            $i = ($this->use_page_numbers) ? $loop : ($loop * $this->per_page) - $this->per_page;

            $attributes = sprintf('%s %s="%d"', $this->_attributes, $this->data_page_attr, (int) $i);

            if ($i >= $base_page)
            {
                if ($this->cur_page === $loop)
                {
                    // Current page
                    $output .= $this->cur_tag_open.$loop.$this->cur_tag_close;
                }
                elseif ($i === $base_page)
                {
                    // First page
                    $output .= $this->num_tag_open.'<a href="'.$first_url.'"'.$attributes.$this->_attr_rel('start').'>'
                        .$loop.'</a>'.$this->num_tag_close;
                }
                else
                {
                    $append = $this->prefix.$i.$this->suffix;
                    $output .= $this->num_tag_open.'<a href="'.$base_url.$append.'"'.$attributes.$this->_attr_rel('start').'>'
                        .$loop.'</a>'.$this->num_tag_close;
                }

            }
        }

        /*
         * On pages before last, show dots
         */ 
        if($end < ($num_pages-1)){
            $output .= '<div class="continues">. . .</div>';
        }

    }

    // Render the "Last" link
    if ($this->last_link !== FALSE && ($this->cur_page + $this->num_links + ! $this->num_links) < $num_pages)
    {
        $i = ($this->use_page_numbers) ? $num_pages : ($num_pages * $this->per_page) - $this->per_page;

        $attributes = sprintf('%s %s="%d"', $this->_attributes, $this->data_page_attr, (int) $i);

        $output .= $this->last_tag_open.'<a href="'.$base_url.$this->prefix.$i.$this->suffix.'"'.$attributes.'>'
            .$this->last_link.'</a>'.$this->last_tag_close;
    }


    // Render the "next" link
    if ($this->next_link !== FALSE && $this->cur_page < $num_pages)
    {
        $i = ($this->use_page_numbers) ? $this->cur_page + 1 : $this->cur_page * $this->per_page;

        $attributes = sprintf('%s %s="%d"', $this->_attributes, $this->data_page_attr, (int) $i);

        $output .= $this->next_tag_open.'<a href="'.$base_url.$this->prefix.$i.$this->suffix.'"'.$attributes
            .$this->_attr_rel('next').'>'.$this->next_link.'</a>'.$this->next_tag_close;
    }



    // Kill double slashes. Note: Sometimes we can end up with a double slash
    // in the penultimate link so we'll kill all double slashes.
    $output = preg_replace('#([^:])//+#', '\\1/', $output);

    // Add the wrapper HTML if exists
    return $this->full_tag_open.$output.$this->full_tag_close;
}
```

}

I have added

```
    /*
     * my comments here
     */
```

styled comments before code where I made changes.

Comment: To avoid off-topic, can you kindly put this in the Codeigniter forum <https://forum.codeigniter.com> with an implementation/use example? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$config['num_links'] = 4;
```

in your $config array.

Answer (score -2):

Try **CSS** here is an example - once used this and it worked

```
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_info.dataTables_paginate .pagination,
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate.dataTables_paginate .pagination {
  margin: 0;
}



    .pagination {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 17px 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.pagination > li {
  display: inline;
}
.pagination > li > a,
.pagination > li > span {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #373e4a;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-left: -1px;
}
.pagination > li:first-child > a,
.pagination > li:first-child > span {
  margin-left: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
}
.pagination > li:last-child > a,
.pagination > li:last-child > span {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}
.pagination > li > a:hover,
.pagination > li > span:hover,
.pagination > li > a:focus,
.pagination > li > span:focus {
  z-index: 2;
  color: #818da2;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  border-color: #ddd;
}
.pagination > .active > a,
.pagination > .active > span,
.pagination > .active > a:hover,
.pagination > .active > span:hover,
.pagination > .active > a:focus,
.pagination > .active > span:focus {
  z-index: 3;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #373e4a;
  border-color: #949494;
  cursor: default;
}
.pagination > .disabled > span,
.pagination > .disabled > span:hover,
.pagination > .disabled > span:focus,
.pagination > .disabled > a,
.pagination > .disabled > a:hover,
.pagination > .disabled > a:focus {
  color: #999999;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #ddd;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
.pagination-lg > li > a,
.pagination-lg > li > span {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.3333333;
}
.pagination-lg > li:first-child > a,
.pagination-lg > li:first-child > span {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
}
.pagination-lg > li:last-child > a,
.pagination-lg > li:last-child > span {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}
.pagination-sm > li > a,
.pagination-sm > li > span {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.pagination-sm > li:first-child > a,
.pagination-sm > li:first-child > span {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
  border-top-left-radius: 2px;
}
.pagination-sm > li:last-child > a,
.pagination-sm > li:last-child > span {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
  border-top-right-radius: 2px;
}
.pager {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 17px 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.pager li {
  display: inline;
}
.pager li > a,
.pager li > span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 14px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.pager li > a:hover,
.pager li > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}
.pager .next > a,
.pager .next > span {
  float: right;
}
.pager .previous > a,
.pager .previous > span {
  float: left;
}
.pager .disabled > a,
.pager .disabled > a:hover,
.pager .disabled > a:focus,
.pager .disabled > span {
  color: #999999;
  background-color: #fff;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

Comment: He asked how to customize pagination Not how to add library in your configuration.

Comment: Thanks. But what are you trying to tell? I have loaded codeigniter pagination library and it is working fine. I just want to find a way to add dots  " ... " for hidden page numbers